# Parse promise returns empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform, promise

I'm iterating an array, but with each iteration, I'm calling an async method.

**Here is the code**

```
var getTaskResponse = function(displayedWidgetId) {

    var promises = [];
    // var promise = new Parse.Promise();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/functions/getWidgetResponse',
        data: {
            "groupWidgetId": displayedWidgetId
        },
        beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", parse_ids.app_id);
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", parse_ids.rest_api);
        }
    })
    .then(function(response){
        var promise = new Parse.Promise();
        var taskIssuedTo = {},

            taskObj = {},
            finalObj = {},
            subTasks = [],
            taskResponse = response.result;


        taskResponse.forEach(function(widgetResponseObj,index) {
            var issuedTo = widgetResponseObj.answeredBy.objectId,
                taskResponseObj = JSON.parse(widgetResponseObj.widgetResponse),
                taskSelected = taskResponseObj.taskSelected,
                date = taskResponseObj.date;

            (function(userId){
                getUsersName(userId).then(function(userName){
                    if (typeof taskIssuedTo[taskSelected] === "undefined") {
                        taskIssuedTo[taskSelected] = [];
                        subTasks = [];
                    }

                    subTasks.push({
                        "user" : userName.result.name,
                        "date" : date
                    });

                    taskIssuedTo[taskSelected] = subTasks;
                    taskObj[taskSelected] = taskIssuedTo[taskSelected];
                });
            }(issuedTo));  
        });
        promise.resolve(taskObj);        
        return promise;
    })
    .then(function(obj){
        console.log("After Promise Return :: "+JSON.stringify(obj));
    });
}
```

In above `for-each loop` **getUsersName** is the method that is getting called. When i'm printing the resolved promise, this is what i got

After Promise Return :: `{"_resolved":true,"_rejected":false,"_resolvedCallbacks":[],"_rejectedCallbacks":[],"_result":{"0":{}}}`.

How should i resolve the promise so that i get desired output?

Comment: @Bergi- It's same as promisesToWaitOn as declared by @Andrew(jst variable name got changed) . It was used to store the promises that I was getting from for-each loop.

Comment: That's what I thought it should be, but then you didn't actually use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that inside `taskResponse.forEach` you are invoking `getUserName` which is asynchronous. You know that when it completes more work will take place, but your outer function is not waiting for the completions to take place.

Here is an approach to take:

```
var getTaskResponse = function (displayedWidgetId) {
    var promiseToReturn = new Parse.Promise();

    // var promise = new Parse.Promise();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/functions/getWidgetResponse',
        data: {
            "groupWidgetId": displayedWidgetId
        },
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", parse_ids.app_id);
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", parse_ids.rest_api);
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        var taskIssuedTo = {},

        taskObj = {},
        finalObj = {},
        subTasks = [],
            taskResponse = response.result;


        var promisesToWaitOn = [];

        taskResponse.forEach(function (widgetResponseObj, index) {
            var issuedTo = widgetResponseObj.answeredBy.objectId,
                taskResponseObj = JSON.parse(widgetResponseObj.widgetResponse),
                taskSelected = taskResponseObj.taskSelected,
                date = taskResponseObj.date;

            promisesToWaitOn.push(function (userId) {
                return getUsersName(userId).then(function (userName) {
                    if (typeof taskIssuedTo[taskSelected] === "undefined") {
                        taskIssuedTo[taskSelected] = [];
                        subTasks = [];
                    }

                    subTasks.push({
                        "user": userName.result.name,
                            "date": date
                    });

                    taskIssuedTo[taskSelected] = subTasks;
                    taskObj[taskSelected] = taskIssuedTo[taskSelected];
                });
            }(issuedTo));
        });
        return Parse.Promise.when(promisesToWaitOn).then(function () {
            promiseToReturn.resolve(taskObj);
        });
    });
    return promiseToReturn;
}
```

If you want to access the results from your function, you would do so like this:

```
getTaskResponse(widgitId).then(function(taskObj) {
     // Here is where you can do something with the generated taskObj
});
```

Comment: your code isn't working, throwing an error saying "resolvedCallback is not a function"

Comment: Actually, I'm calling the above getTaskResponse() from another function, and from there I want to access the resolved promise. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Tushar2098 - I've added another code snippet to the answer to help you.

Comment: @Tushar2098 - That's because `getTaskResponse` wasn't returning anything. You want it to return a promise. I've modified the code again.

Comment: The function that builds `taskObj` looks like it should simplify quite considerably.